# Create optional sub-packages in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, package, project-structure

I have my project structure something like this.

```
|--utils
|  |
|  |--MyFileReader.java
```

But I want to change it into this one.

```
utils
|
|--readers
|  |
|  |--MyFileReader.java
```

Can anyone tell me the preffered way to do that with **intellij** preserving all dependencies and usages?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it: Create the package, and drag and drop the class inside the new package. Intellij will do the rest. ([link to help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/move-refactorings.html))

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time in searching and @morpheus05 answer with link helped to summarize two ways (AFAIK)

***Method One***

1. Right click the class in the project explorer and `Refactor -> Move` or Select the Class in the project explorer press <kbd>F6</kbd>
2. Then select `To Package` enter the new package name and press `Refactor` button.

***Method Two***

Just change the package statement in MyDBReader.java from `package daos;` to `package daos.readers;`, then you will see red line under the package statement, place the cursor on the statement then do <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> then select 'Move package to daos.readers'. **This method only changes the package but does not update the usages**